# Sort NSArray based on another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a little problem
First, i have custom object:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *parentName;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger childId;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger parentId;
@end
```

Second custom object:

```
@interface Children : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *childrenName;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger childId;
@end
```

Now i have an array like this

```
ArrayA = @[Child3, Child1, Child3];
ArrayB = @[Parent1, Parent2, Parent3];
```

How can i sort this ArrayA base on *parentId* of ArrayB

Comment: There is no relation between Parent and Child so there is no easy way of doing this. You first need to sort Parent array and then based on the order of that array. Are you sure you don't want the Child class to be a subclass of Parent? Can child exist without Parent? Or parent have a reference to all its children and/or children have reference to Parent.

Comment: Parent and Child have a relation with childId..Because some reason and can make Child class to be a subclass..

Comment: Sure but not in the way that you can access that from the child instance. If you can't change this structure you will have to access the parent array and search for the parent object that corresponds to the child objects id and sort that way.

Comment: I can provide a solution, but just to confirm that multiple parents can have a single child1, right..?

Comment: Multi child can have a single parent, need reverse that.

Comment: "Multi child can have a single parent" - so why `Parent` is holding 1 `childId`? Wouldn't it be more logical to remove the childID or replace it by a real relation via `NSSet` and add the `parentId` to the child?

Comment: Where does this pattern come from? I see it being asked every now and then.